# Is it a correct way of doing loops to open urls in python

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")

cnt = 0
for i in range(0, len(df)):
  cnt += 1
  driver.get(df['urls'][0])
```

'df' contains 4 urls in a column with a heading 'urls', and I'd like to open them one by one like:

open 1st url 
leave comment 
close

open 2nd url 
leave comment 
close

..iterate

I tried varied ways of performing loops, but all didn't work out.

Can you please give some tips to make this work out?

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do the following:

```
for url in df["urls"]:
    driver.get(url)
    ### Do stuff here with webdriver
```

This way you are looping through the urls in the `"urls"` of your `df`